# Ionic 2 In App Browser - Keep user within app, currently all website links go to Safari

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, inappbrowser

I am wrapping a web app I have built in an Ionic 2 application so the client can release on the app store(s).

I am using:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/

Which correctly loads up my testing IP but any anchor tags open up in the normal Safari browser. How can I keep the user within the in app browser?

This is how I set up the browser:

```
const browser = this.iab.create('my.ip.add.ress');
browser.show();
```

I have tried changing the links on my website to use all of the following variations:

```
target="_blank"
target="_system"
target="_self"
```

But nothing works.

Comment: I guess this won't work with a web app (that you access via http://).

Comment: Using the cordova in app browser instead of the ionic native one works for me `let ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(authorize_url, '_blank', 'location=yes');`